# Perforce API (.NET): File sync is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, perforce, p4api.net

Using 2014.1.85.4506 API version. Just trying retrieve files from within a depot to be on in the workspace.

I have an object with a local variables `string localPath`, `string depotPath`, `string clientPath` (which is the same as `localPath`), `Repository repo` and `Connection con`.

My code thus looks like:

```
// ...
DepotPath       depotSpec  = new DepotPath(depoPath);
ClientPath      clientSpec = new ClientPath(clientPath);
LocalPath       localSpec  = new LocalPath(localPath);

FileSpec        fileSpec   = new FileSpec(depoSpec, clientSpec, localSpec, VersionSpec.Head);

IList<FileSpec> fileSpecs  = new List<FileSpec>();
fileSpecs.Add(fileSpec);

IList<FileSpec> synced     = con.Client.SyncFiles(fileSpecs, null);
// ...
```

and `synced` always ends up being `null`. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's `con.Client` set to? Is it pointing to a workspace that actually contains the paths being synced?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, does SyncFiles returns null or an empty list?

If it returns an empty list, I had that happen when I already had the latest revision locally. Because there is nothing to be synced, it returns an empty list.